# SQL Server Time Format is not equal to Client Side Time format

Tags: javascript, php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm trying to compare the client side time format `("14:00")` to SQL Server time format `("14:00:00.0000000")` with SQL Query, technically is not equal because SQL Server time format has seconds and milliseconds, so I tried to concatenate the seconds and milliseconds to client side time format in PHP script like this `14:00.":00.0000000"` and yet is not equal to SQL Server time format.

My script in PHP:

```
// I assume that the $_POST['pAppointmentTime'] variable has a value of 14:00.
$pAppointTime = $_POST['pAppointmentTime'];                                      
$pAppointTime = $pAppointTime.":00.0000000";  

// SQL query 
"SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE 
   pAppointment_Date = '".$pAppointSchedDate."' ".
   "AND pAppointment_Time='".$pAppointTime."'".
   " AND Department='".$selectedDept."';"
```

So how can I compare these two with SQL Query and PHP Script?

Comment: Can you post your current attempt - the PHP script and SQL statement?

Comment: Here my script in php `$pAppointTime = $_POST['pAppointmentTime'];  
                                $pAppointTime = $pAppointTime.":00.0000000";` assume that the `$_POST['pAppointmentTime']` variable has a value of `14:00`. and here my sql query `"SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE pAppointment_Date = '".$pAppointSchedDate."' "."AND pAppointment_Time='".$pAppointTime."'"." AND Department='".$selectedDept."';"` @Zhorov

Comment: Thanks, something you need to consider: 1) You are concatenating strings to build a statement, so you are possibly open to SQL onjection. Please, use parameters in your statements (... what driver do you use to connect to SQL Server); 2) What is the data type of `pAppointment_Time` column; 3) Supported String Literal Formats for time from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-string-literal-formats-for-time). My personal advice is to rewrite the PHP script and use parameterized statement.

Comment: I understand thank you for your advice, the datatype of `pAppointment_Time` is TIME(7)

Comment: What driver do you use to connect to SQL Server - PHP Driver for SQL Server (SQLSRV or PDO_SQLSRV), ODBC or somthing else?

Comment: I'm using PDO_SQLSRV @Zhorov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may consider the following:

- Do not concatenate strings to build a statement and use parameters in your statements to prevent possible SQL injection issues.
- Pass date and time values as text using unambiguous date and time formats - `yyyymmdd` and `hh:mm:ss`.
- For your specific case, you may try to compare the `date` and `time` values using explicit cast and adding only seconds for the `time` values.

An example, that is a possible solution to your problem:

```
<?php
// Connection info
$server = 'server\instance';
$database = 'database';
$uid = 'uid';
$pwd = 'pwd';

// Connection
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $uid, $pwd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server".$e->getMessage());
}

// Parameters
$pAppointSchedDate = "date in yyyymmdd format";
$pAppointTime = $_POST['pAppointmentTime'];                                      
$pAppointTime = $pAppointTime.":00"; 
$selectedDept = "...";

// Statement
try {
    $sql = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM appointment 
        WHERE 
           CONVERT(date, pAppointment_Date) = CONVERT(date, ?) AND 
           CONVERT(time(0), pAppointment_Time) = CONVERT(time(0), ?) AND 
           Department = ? 
    ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $pAppointSchedDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $pAppointTime, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $selectedDept, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
        echo print_r($row, true)."<br>";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die ("Error executing query. ".$e->getMessage());
}

// End
$stmt = null;
$conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong syntax in PHP script 14:00.":00.0000000"

the use of double quotes should be from start to end like --> "14:00:00.0000000"

Comment: the `14:00` is a variable value so it looks like this `$client_Side_Time = 14:00 ` and I concatenated the variable to seconds and milliseconds like this `$client_Side_Time.":00.0000000"`